# Thymeleaf - how to link <select> th:value with message bundle?

Tags: internationalization, thymeleaf

I have this select:

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{objId}" name="objId" >
    <option th:each="obj : ${objList}"
            th:value="${obj.getId()}"
            th:selected="${objList.contains(obj)}"                              
            th:text="${obj.getDescription()}">
    </option>
</select>
```

The description for the default object obj is 'Object not valid'.

Is it possible to internationalize its value? So when the object appears on this list it reads for instance, in Portuguese, "Objeto"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use internationalization you should use separate message file for each language you support and display description as follows:

```
th:text="#{${obj.getDescription()}}">
```

but in this case `obj.getDescription()` should return message key as its value (for example `object.description.message`), and this key has to be present in `messages_pt.properties` file like for example:

```
object.description.message="Objecto"
```

Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, and you want only display different value when description is null. In this case the code below should resolve problem:

```
th:text="${obj.getDescription()}?: 'Description is null...'"
```

or

```
th:text="${obj.getDescription()}?: #{message.property.key.here}"
```

HTH